# What is the general definition of a quench?

Tags: terminology, definition

I've seen the term "quench" used in many different contexts.

It's easy to understand the meaning when the context has a simple physical analogue, such as lowering the temperature of a system to cause a phase transition, or the extinction of fluorescence.

It's harder to understand in less intuitive contexts, such as a quantum quench, or the addition of topological constraints.

Is there a general definition that clarifies the usage of quench?

Comment: Sadly, in language, a 'general definition' rarely leads to clarity of usage in general, much less in various sub-disciplines.